# Why doesn't my HDD work?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

So I just built my first PC and it works except for that I can't use the HDD. I also have an SSD in the System, so that's where I installed my Windows on. But I can't see the HDD in the System information or in the Windows explorer, so I can't save any data on the HDD. Why doesn't my System recognize it?

Comment: How are the HDD and SSD connected to the motherboard?

Comment: They are both connected to the MoBo with a Sata cable.

Comment: Btw i am using windows 10 and the HDD is a Toshiba P300.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard might have the SATA port disabled in BIOS.  Turn off the PC, on another PC look up how to engage BIOS mode on startup, usually one of the Function keys, and start it up.

The power cable might have failed.  Try turning off the PC and swapping the one that you know works (behind the SSD).

The SATA cable might have failed.  Try turning off the PC and swapping the one that you know works (behind the SSD).

It's possible that the HDD has failed.  If you did the previous two steps, the HDD has likely failed.  You can also try a USB->SATA adapter, which you would have to buy or borrow.

Rarely, specific HDDs are incompatible with specific motherboards or OSes.  I once had an iMac that could not connect to a specific Western Digital HDD, despite it working in all other circumstances.